# Sorting based on created_at table after joins two table in rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, join

I have 4 models: `User`, `Micropost`, `Answer`, and `Activity`. `Activity` belongs to `Micropost`. I want to join the `Micropost` table and `Activities` table and sort the results based on the `created_at` column in `Activities` where `user_id` in `Activities` is the current user. This is my method feed:

```
def feed
  Micropost.joins(:activities).where('activities.user_id=?',id)
  .order('activities.created_at DESC')
end
```

But the output is still sorted by `Micropost` `created_at` column. I changed order to reorder; still same result. I googled a lot and logic seems to be correct. Can some one help? Thanks in advance.

I understood the problem. Activity model has two columns where is stores micropost ids. one with micropost_id and other action_id. Its joining through action_id. How can I change that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query does look correct, so I'm assuming the issue is as you describe in your edit (the join is happening through the wrong ID). Rails decides how to join two tables based on the relations that you've set up, so if the join isn't as you'd expect then you need to make sure your relations are correct. In your case, you would want something like:

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :activities
  has_many :action_activities, class_name: 'Activity', foreign_key: :action_id
end

class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :micropost
  belongs_to :action, class_name: 'Micropost'
end
```

Since Micropost is related to Activity in two different ways, it needs to be told that explicitly. I used the `foreign_key` option to make sure it knows which is which. With that code, you can see that this generates the expected SQL:

```
irb> Micropost.joins(:action_activities)
  Micropost Load (2.8ms)  SELECT "microposts".* FROM "microposts" INNER JOIN "activities" ON "activities"."action_id" = "microposts"."id"
```

The other option is to be explicit in your join, like so:

```
Micropost.joins("JOIN activities ON activities.action_id = microposts.id")
  .where('activities.user_id=?',id)
  .order('activities.created_at DESC')
```

Which is useful in situations when you want a more complicated join, mostly. In your case, I think your relations are the real issue.

Comment: hey..thanks man.. I sorted it out.. but it developed a new problem. can you help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31624159/order-with-distinct-ids-in-rails-with-postgres