# Order with DISTINCT ids in rails with postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have the following code to join two tables microposts and activities with micropost_id column and then order based on created_at of activities table with distinct micropost id.

```
 Micropost.joins("INNER JOIN activities ON 
 (activities.micropost_id = microposts.id)").
 where('activities.user_id= ?',id).order('activities.created_at DESC').
 select("DISTINCT (microposts.id), *")
```

which should return whole micropost columns.This is not working in my developement enviornment.

```
(PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
```

If I add activities.created_at in SELECT DISTINCT, I will get repeated micropost ids because the have distinct activities.created_at column. I have done a lot of search to reach here. But the problem always persist because of this postgres condition to avoid random selection.

I want to select based on order of activities.created_at with distinct micropost _id.

Please help..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start with, we need to quickly cover what `SELECT DISTINCT` is actually doing. It *looks* like just a nice keyword to make sure you only get back distinct values, which shouldn't change anything, right? Except as you're finding out, behind the scenes, `SELECT DISTINCT` is actually acting more like a `GROUP BY`. If you want to select distinct values of something, you can only order that result set by the same values you're selecting -- otherwise, Postgres doesn't know what to do.

To explain where the ambiguity comes from, consider this simple set of data for your `activities`:

```
CREATE TABLE activities (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  created_at TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
  micropost_id INTEGER REFERENCES microposts(id)
);
INSERT INTO activities (id, created_at, micropost_id)
VALUES (1, current_timestamp,                      1),
       (2, current_timestamp - interval '3 hours', 1),
       (3, current_timestamp - interval '2 hours', 2)
```

You stated in your question that you want "distinct micropost_id" "based on order of activities.created_at". It's easy to order these activities by descending created_at (`1, 3, 2`), but both `1` and `2` have the same micropost_id of 1. So if you want the query to return just micropost IDs, should it return `1, 2` or `2, 1`?

If you can answer the above question, you need to take your logic for doing so and move it into your query. Let's say that, and I think this is pretty likely, you want this to be a list of microposts which were most recently acted on. In that case, you want to sort the microposts in descending order of their *most recent activity*. Postgres can do that for you, in a number of ways, but the easiest way in my mind is this:

```
SELECT micropost_id
FROM activities
JOIN microposts ON activities.micropost_id = microposts.id
GROUP BY micropost_id
ORDER BY MAX(activities.created_at) DESC
```

Note that I've dropped the `SELECT DISTINCT` bit in favor of using `GROUP BY`, since Postgres handles them much better. The `MAX(activities.created_at)` bit tells Postgres to, for each group of activities with the same micropost_id, sort by only the most recent.

You can translate the above to Rails like so:

```
Micropost.select('microposts.*')
  .joins("JOIN activities ON activities.micropost_id = microposts.id")
  .where('activities.user_id' => id)
  .group('microposts.id')
  .order('MAX(activities.created_at) DESC')
```

Hope this helps! You can play around with [this sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/29b37/5/0) if you want to understand more about how the query works.

Comment: Will it return all the microposts table rows or just the idea. If it doesnt , is there a way to get all the rows with single query?

Comment: The final snippet of Rails code will return what I believe you're looking for (distinct Microposts, ordered by their latest activity). I'd suggest you read my whole post to better understand why, though!

Comment: I get his error with your code 
PG::GroupingError: ERROR: column "microposts.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
so I changed group('micropost_id') to group('microposts.id'). Its working but its not sorted on activities.created_at. I doubt if it sort on created_at only when ids are same..

Comment: Sorry about the typo; your correction is right. What order do you expect? Like I explained above, there can be multiple values of `activities.created_at` for each Micropost, so you need to specify an ordering that takes that fact into account. I chose to order by their most recent activity's created_on value, descending. It might help if you uploaded a small dataset somewhere with your input data, table structure, and what your expected result is.

Comment: The raw sql works but the Rails code doesnt. I am unable to understand why? It is not giving output in the order of created_at of activities table.

Comment: Can you provide any way to reproduce this? Locally, I set up an app with the same models as yours and I'm able to get the code to produce results ordered correctly.

Comment: Hey.. I had a default scope which I created sometime back. That was causing all this trouble. Thanks for the help. Your code works... :) And can your provide a place where I can learn this postgresql better; other than official page. Thats really confusing for a begginner like me.

Comment: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-group-by/ is a decent introduction to GROUP BY, but the best way by far to learn it is to play around in Postgres! sqlfiddle.com is great for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
Micropost.select('microposts.*, activities.created_at')
.joins("INNER JOIN activities ON (activities.micropost_id = microposts.id)")
.where('activities.user_id= ?',id)
.order('activities.created_at DESC')
.uniq
```

Comment: Its not returning unique Microposts.. Dont understand why?